# Does the following function have a root in $[0,\pi/2]$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

> $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^x-x^n\sin(x)}{1+x^n}$$
>
> Does this function have a root in $[0, \frac \pi 2]$?

In my opinion, it does have a root, as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\frac \pi 2) \to -1$. Therefore, $f(\frac \pi 2)\cdot f(0) < 0$ and since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, it has a root in the given interval.

Could someone please check if this logic is correct? According to the textbook, it does not have a root in this interval. I believe I am making an error in assuming that it is a continuous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **No**.

> In my opinion, it does have a root, as $f(0) = 1$ and $f(\frac \pi 2) \to -1$. Therefore, $f(\frac \pi 2)\cdot f(0) < 0$ and since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, it has a root in the given interval.

As you know you can apply this when a function is continuous, But this function isn't.

---

If $0\leq x <1,$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = 0$

So we know $f(x)=2^x $ when $x\in[0, 1)$.

When $x=1,$ just put $x=1,$ we get $f(1)=\frac{2-\sin1}{2}.$

If $x>1,$ we know $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n = \infty$ so we divide numerator and demoninator with $\frac{1}{x^n}.$

Then evaluate the limit, we have $f(x)=-\sin x$ when $x\in\left(1,\frac{\pi}{2}\right].$

Can you end this now?

Comment: does $lim_{n \to \infty} x^n$ have a *sharp discontinuity* at x=1? woudn't this function be continuous at x=1 since $n \in R$?